# Нужно в FireBase получить строки в которых есть нужный параметр

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть база в FireBase. Мне нужно вывести те строки в которых `id_cat=1`. как мне это сделать? и как получить `ID` ключ? если я хочу обновить количество заказов в корзине по `ID` как это нужно делать: по внешнему `ID` или внутреннему `id`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `equalTo(1, "id_cat")` [документация](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)

Comment: А как мне это писать? я пишу в адаптере так, но у меня ничего не показывает

Comment: Читайте документацию, там есть примеры. Пишите код. Если будут ошибки, добавляйте код в вопрос.